# Hide a <div> when scrolled to the bottom with javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, onscroll

I signed up a few minutes ago to ask my question to you dear community.

I have already tried to get ahead with similar questions, unfortunately without success.

Javascript is not my forte

I am detecting with php if it is a Mobile Device to show them a mobile navigationbar like this.
The navigation bar is positioned at the bottom (and hides my Copyright Text).

```
if(isMobileDevice()){
require __DIR__. '/mobile-navbar.php';
}
```

my mobile-navbar.php looks so

```
<div class="uver-mobile-navbar" id="mobile-navbar">
  <a href="#uver" class="active">uver</a>
  <a href="#uver">uver</a>
  <a href="#uver">uver</a>
  <a href="#uver">uver</a>
  <a href="#uver">uver</a>
</div>
```

and my mobile-navbar.js looks so

```
document.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY > document.body.clientHeight) {
        document.getElementById('mobile-navbar').style.display='none';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('mobile-navbar').style.display='block';
    }
}
```

The problem is that as soon as I scroll, the div disappears.
When I scroll up it doesn't appear anymore.

I thank you in advance for your support.

Best Regards
Ridvan

Comment: How is the mobile-navbar positioned with CSS?

Comment: why not use media queries in CSS?

Comment: The navigation bar is positioned at the bottom (and hides my Copyright Text)

Comment: .uver-mobile-navbar {
 position:fixed;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:1000;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 height:60px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:black;
 
}

.uver-mobile-navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
}

.uver-mobile-navbar a:hover {
  background: #5a5c5a;
  color: black;
}

.uver-mobile-navbar a.active {
  background-color: #f9b42b;
  color: white;
}